# c# padding to string

Tags: c#, sql, import-from-excel

Am reading from an excel sheet column and need to save into an sql table.
this is what the fiedl looks like in excel;'33349836', but I need it to be saved this way in the database '0033349836', because that field needs to be 10characters.

Comment: Sounds good. What is your question?

Comment: How do I go about padding with zero's in front, so that I get required 10 characters

Comment: try  `str.PadLeft(10,'0');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PadLeft()` function to add zeros to your string.

Try This:

```
var str = "33349836";
str = str.PadLeft(10,'0');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.PadLeft Method (Int32, Char)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Returns a new string that right-aligns the characters in this instance
>   **by padding them on the left with a specified Unicode character, for a
>   specified total length.**

```
string s = "33349836";
string newstring = s.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Remember, `0033349836` will be a string representation of your numeric values. Don't keep this kind of data in a numeric column type. Keep it in a some character type of column like [`nvarchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this using C#.

One such way is this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "33349836";

        int width = 10;
        char padding = '0';

        string s1 = s.PadLeft(width, padding);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
    }
```

That code will output these values:

```
33349836
0033349836
```